# Load photo from gallery

Tags: ios, image, nsurl

I have an `NSURL` of a photo from the camera roll and I'd like to load the image or the `NSData` from it.

I try this:

```
NSData *imageDataTemp = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:path];
```

but it return half of the size of the image.

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with images. Please update your question with code relevant to an image and further explain what the problem is with the image.

Comment: how did u manage to get the nsurl of pic from the camera roll ?

Comment: its for a share extension. i select photo to share and get the url in my view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to load an image having the `ALAsset` URL.

### Using ALAssetLibrary (deprecated in iOS 9.0 )

```
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultBlock = ^(ALAsset *asset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef image = [representation fullResolutionImage];

    if (image) 
    {
        yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
    }
};

ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureBlock  = ^(NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
};

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library assetForURL:assetURL 
         resultBlock:resultBlock
        failureBlock:failureBlock];
```

### Using PHPhotoLibrary

```
    NSURL *yourALAssetURL;
    PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[yourALAssetURL] options:nil];
    PHAsset *asset = result.firstObject;

    if (asset)
    {
        PHCachingImageManager *imageManager = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];

        // Request an image for the asset from the PHCachingImageManager.
        [imageManager requestImageForAsset:asset
                                targetSize:CGSizeMake(100.0f, 100.0f)
                               contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                   options:nil
                             resultHandler:^(UIImage *image,
                                             NSDictionary *info)
         {
             NSLog(@"IMAGE: %@", image);
         }];
    }
```

Apple created a sample app that uses PHPhotoLibrary. It's available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014575-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).

Comment: I know that ALAssetLibrary is Deprecated in iOS 9.0. And the replacement is PHPhotoLibrary, but i can't find example using it

Comment: I figured it out and updated my answer. Please check it out.